# How to hide and properly place menus in media queries?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsiveness

I have a super simple horizontal menu in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omarjuvera/koj3701v/)

However I have several problems when trying to make it responsive.
First, on large screens, the menu button should not be present. But the query is not working.

Then, in small screens, only the menu button should be visible, and the other links visible when hover/tap/click...but when I tried it in the query, it would hide the other links and can't make them available

On small screens, the menu does changes to `display: block` (desired behavior) but it is not "floating" over the header. Instead, it is making the whole header taller.

Finally, the buy-now button. I can't get it to vertically center in small screens

```css
/* ************************************
General
************************************ */
html, body, header, main { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html, body { color: #292828; font-family: ‘Trebuchet MS’, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
header, main { display: block; width: 100%; }
body { background-color: #cccccc; }
header { background-color: #292828; height: 70px; max-height: 70px;
 /* Overlay */
 position: fixed; top:0; left: 0; z-index: 999;
}


/* ************************************
Menus
************************************ */
#menu-links li {
 display: inline-block;
}
#menu-links li a {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 0.75em;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;

 height: 30px;
 padding: 0em 1em 0em 1em;

 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
}
.buy-now a {
 border: 2px solid #44dbbd;
 border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
 background-color: #44dbbd;
 transition: color 2s ease-out;
}
.buy-now:hover { background-color: #292828; }


/* ************************************
Media queries
************************************ */
@media (min-width:10em) { 
/* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */ 
 header { height: 40px; }
  main { padding: 40px; }
  #menu-links-button { display: block }
 #menu-links { background-color: #292828; }
 #menu-links li { display: block; }
 #menu-links li a { line-height: 10px; }
}
@media (min-width:20em) { 
/* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */ 
 header { height: 70px; }
  main { padding: 70px; }
  #menu-links-button { display: none; }
  #menu-links { background-color: #292828; }
 #menu-links li { display: inline-block; }
 #menu-links li a { line-height: 30px; }
  
}
```

```html
<header>
    <ul id="menu-links">
        <li id="menu-links-button"><a href="#">&#9776;</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Blog</a></li>
        <li id="buy-now" class="buy-now"><a href="#">Buy Now</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>


<main>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
</main>
```

Comment: Hello, I think I can help you with that, but I need more precise description. How exactly do you expect the menu to look like on small screen? Do you plan to make it a drop down menu, or just a list of blocked content? On small screen like mobile there's no :hover state so a expand-on-hover menu would be inappropriate.

Comment: @av-avt In small screens, I would like it to be a drop down menu. When the user taps on the menu button, to drop down all the available menu links. And in big screens, a horizontal menu (without the menu button)